# disk partitions don't mount to filesystems after reboot

Tags: centos, filesystems, mount, virtual-machine

i have a VM machine that rebooted last night and we could't connect to it via ssh. i used console and saw that only `/` and `swap` are mounted with `lsblk` command:

```
  NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
  sr0     11:0    1 1024M  0 rom
  sdb      8:16   0    8G  0 disk
  ├─sdb1   8:17   0    2G  0 part 
  └─sdb2   8:18   0    6G  0 part [SWAP]
  sdc      8:32   0   20G  0 disk
  └─sdc1   8:33   0   20G  0 part 
  sde      8:64   0  400M  0 disk
  └─sde1   8:65   0  399M  0 part 
  sda      8:0    0   20G  0 disk
  └─sda1   8:1    0   20G  0 part /
 sdd      8:48   0   20G  0 disk
 └─sdd1   8:49   0   20G  0 part 
 sdf      8:80   0   10G  0 disk
 └─sdf1   8:81   0   10G  0 part
```

but when i ran `df -h`:

```
  Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
  /dev/sda1        20G  1.2G   18G   7% /
  tmpfs           7.8G     0   7.8G   0% /dev/shm
  /dev/sde1        20G    1.2G  18G   7% /boot
  /dev/sdd1        20G    1.2G  18G   7% /data
  /dev/sdc1        20G    1.2G  18G   7% /opt
  /dev/sdb1        20G    1.2G  18G   7% /var
  /dev/sdf1        20G    1.2G  18G   7% /backup
```

when i ran `ls -hal` on them they were all empty except for `/`.i tried to unmount and mount partitions i got error that partitions are not mount. i mounted them all again for example:

`mount /dev/sdf1 /backup`

and `df -h`:

```
 Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1        20G  1.2G   18G   7% /
tmpfs           7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sde1       387M   40M  327M  11% /boot
/dev/sdd1        20G   14G  4.9G  75% /data
/dev/sdc1        20G  1.4G   18G   8% /opt
/dev/sdb1       2.0G  155M  1.8G   9% /var
/dev/sdf1       9.9G  2.4G  7.0G  26% /backup
```

and everything is fine. i rebooted to test it. it happened again. only `/` and swap were mounted. `blkid` output:

```
   /dev/sdb1: UUID="3a11afe1-52d5-4e31-96a0-66da2c8e70eb" TYPE="ext3"
   /dev/sdf1: UUID="0e1f69a7-36d9-4af1-a537-afaa211e87d7" TYPE="ext3"
   /dev/sdb2: UUID="416970f8-c21b-419b-90d5-eb8eabb685a6" TYPE="swap"
   /dev/sdc1: UUID="d380ddf8-3476-46b3-8e80-9dd3b394dd13" TYPE="ext3"
   /dev/sde1: UUID="b224fa8a-e909-432e-927e-4a98fe2d74d0" TYPE="ext3"
   /dev/sda1: UUID="9407e385-168c-4e37-9651-1de04406b620" SEC_TYPE="ext2" 
   TYPE="ext3"
   /dev/sdd1: UUID="e8439366-d29d-43c3-ad5e-635855f4e42e" TYPE="ext3"
```

part of `cat /etc/fstab` output:

```
  UUID=9407e385-168c-4e37-9651-1de04406b620 /         ext3    defaults   0 0
  UUID=b224fa8a-e909-432e-927e-4a98fe2d74d0 /boot     ext3    defaults   0 0
  UUID=e8439366-d29d-43c3-ad5e-635855f4e42e /data     ext3    defaults   0 0
  UUID=d380ddf8-3476-46b3-8e80-9dd3b394dd13 /opt      ext3    defaults   0 0
  UUID=3a11afe1-52d5-4e31-96a0-66da2c8e70eb /var      ext3    defaults   0 0
  UUID=416970f8-c21b-419b-90d5-eb8eabb685a6 swap      swap    defaults   0 0
  UUID=0e1f69a7-36d9-4af1-a537-afaa211e87d7 /backup   ext3    defaults   0 0
```

why this happens?

Comment: Is the line split for the first line of `fstab` intentional? Or is that just a formatting error?

Comment: `lsblk` doesn't tell you what's mounted. That's what `mount` is for.

Comment: @Haxiel error.updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe someone or something has caused `/etc/mtab` to become un-writeable (immutable file? filesystem errors keeping the root filesystem read-only?), and it contains old data from before the reboot. As a result, the `mount` and `df` commands think the filesystems are already mounted, even though they really aren't.

Check for filesystems in read-only state: `grep ro, /proc/mounts`

Check for immutable `/etc/mtab`: `lsattr /etc/mtab`

Use the `chattr -i /etc/mtab` command to remove the `i`mmutable flag from `/etc/mtab` if necessary.

In modern systems, `/etc/mtab` is increasingly often a symbolic link to `/proc/mounts` or `/proc/self/mounts`. If your system/distribution has an old version of the `mount` command, such linking may cause the mount option `user` to fail, as it cannot record the name of the user that mounted a particular filesystem to `/etc/mtab`. If you don't use the `user` mount option, you can create this symbolic link on older systems too.

The advantage of this linking is that errors like you're experiencing cannot happen, as `/proc/mounts` (or `/proc/self/mounts` on systems with namespace support) always has up-to-date information on mounted filesystems, straight from the kernel itself.

Newer versions of the `mount` command will use `/run/mount` for this purpose instead if `/etc/mtab` is linked to `/proc/self/mounts`.

If you find `/etc/mtab` has been set immutable, and find no other reason for it, you might have been hacked, as making `/etc/mtab` immutable could be a way for an intruder to hide their tools from casual observation...

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that your root filesystem was set read-only before the system shut down, and the `umount` commands used to unmount all disks were unable to remove entries from `/etc/mtab`. On boot, the `mount -a` command ("mount everything that's not already mounted") looked at `/etc/mtab` and determined everything was already mounted so no action was required.

This would explain all of your symptoms:
- mounts failing to be applied at boot
- `df -h` command showing essentially the same disk for several mountpoints
- "not mounted" errors when you tried to unmount apparently mounted filesystems
- mounting working after the umount attempts.

As has been [suggested](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/501296/100397) by [telcoM](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/258991/telcom) it may be better to replace the file `/etc/mtab` with a symbolic link to `/proc/mounts`. But take this advice with caution: it may break your system if it's not set up to expect this.

Answer (score 0):

i have read [roaima](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/100397/roaima) and [telcoM](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/258991/telcom) answers and found out that all filesystems including `/` are READ-ONLY. i checked kernel messages `dmesg` and found out that SELinux was preventing VM partitions to be mounted. well everthing was read only and i couldn't disable SELinux in `/etc/selinux/config` so i used UBUNTUlive, disabled SELinux, rebooted my system and everything is good and back to normal.

Comment: Good to hear it's sorted now. But please don't write an answer that says the same as one of the existing answers. Instead, use the tick-mark to accept the answer that best suited you.

Comment: https://stopdisablingselinux.com